# Can't seem to get AngularJS one-way binding to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I recently started using the (not so new) components for an old angular app. I'm trying to make [some dumb components](https://www.angular2patterns.com/08_container_and_presentational_components.html) for trivial stuff like `<button/>`s and the like.

For some reason, I can't seem to get one way bindings to work!

The `level` binding in the `difficultyButton` component (in `difficult-button.js`) always returns `undefined`, but the `onLevelChosen` binding (again, in `difficulty-button.js`) seems to have the callback that the `options` component passed to it.

Do any of you see where I might've gone wrong?

---

Here is a jsbin link demonstrating this problem : http://jsbin.com/rixukuh/11/edit?html,js

Notice how the classes `red`, `green` and `blue` never get applied because they could never catch hold of the value of `vm.level`.

Also, the console always prints out `LEVEL => undefined`, irrespective of what button is clicked.

---

**FULL CODE**

Here's the full code, if more context is needed.

`options.tpl.html`

```
<div class="full-page-cover">
 <div class="options-grid">
    <!-- some random markup -->
    <div class="buttons-grid">       
        <difficulty-button 
            level="easy"
            on-level-chosen="vm.chooseDifficulty(level)" >
            I'm just here for having fun!
        </difficulty-button>
        <!-- some more `difficulty-buttons` -->
    </div>                    
  </div>
</div>
```

`options.js`

```
import angular from 'angular';
import DifficultyButtonModule from './difficulty-button.js';
import template from './options.tpl.html';

class OptionsController {
   constructor() { /* ... */ }
   chooseDifficulty(level) { /* ... */ }
}

const OptionsModule = angular.module('options', [DifficultyButtonModule.name])

OptionsModule.component('options', {
  template,
  controller: OptionsController,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
});

export default OptionsModule;
```

`difficulty-button.tpl.html`

```
<button 
    ng-class="[
       'uk-button uk-button-large',
       {
         easy: 'uk-button-default',
         medium: 'uk-button-primary',
         hard: 'uk-button-danger'
       } [ vm.level ]
     ]" 
     ng-click="vm.onLevelChosen({ level: vm.level })"
     ng-transclude>

</button>
```

`difficulty-button.js`

```
import angular from 'angular';
import template from './difficulty-button.tpl.html';

const DifficultyButtonModule = angular.module('difficultyButton', []);                                    
DifficultyButtonModule.component('difficultyButton', {
  template,
  bindings: { 
    level: '<', 
    onLevelChosen: '&' 
  }, 
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  transclude: true
});

export default DiffButtonModule;
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- sure! let me whip one up.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- check my edit! I've added a jsbin file

Comment: just hope you using something more clever than document.querySelector('#difficulty-btn-tpl').innerText in real code

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - yes! `import template from './difficulty-button.tpl.html';` is how I do it in the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do this

```
level="easy"
```

you're binding against easy property in your scope (like `$scope.easy`). Which of course does not exist. If you want to bind against the string value directly from your html, you need to use single quotes

```
level="'easy'"
```

and the same for the other levels. That will work fine.

If you still want to use bind against object, you will need to create them in them your scope. But since you need one way only, using string should work fine

**Disclaimer**: I haven't worked with components, so it might be that the explanation is incorrect. I have just worked with angularjs

Comment: WHOA! that was dead on! Works now. Thanks a ton :)

That said, I always thought the `controllerAs` syntax allowed the `$scope` objects to be accessed via the name we provide, in this case, `"vm"`. There is a chance that the `"easy"` might've been looked up in global scope, maybe?